# Sound problems after connecting USB or bluetooth headset

Tags: sound

Basically everytime I use USB headset or bluetooth speakers, I have to reinstall Pulseaudio afterwards, otherwise there is no sound.

If I don't reinstall, I can get sound back by launching VLC and switching back and fort between bluetooth headset and internal sound in audio settings, but then I have to do it everytime I launch VLC or any other application and its quite annoying, not to say that it causes weird issues on its own, like front speakers of my laptop are not functioning properly, unless the lid is at a certain angle(like almost maxed out angle). You'd think there is an issue with worn out wires from opening or closing the lid, but the issue seems to be totally gone after reinstalling pulseaudio, so go figure..

Why does this happen like this? What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

My theory that happens because pulseaudio receives certain signals from your laptop like "lid is closed, my owner is not listening to me, shut up now.".

Try to configure pulseaudio's volumes over `pavucontrol`. Perhaps the Output gets muted? If you don't have the program yet, install the same named package.